# N1QL timeout settings Couchbase Python SDK 3.0.x

Tags: python, timeout, couchbase, sql++

I haven't been able to figure out how to set the query timeout to greater than 1m15s after upgrading to Couchbase's new Python SDK (version 3.0.1). Below is my code and even though it appears that I'm increasing the timeout, I still get the error `N1QL Execution failed, OBJ={'code': 1080, 'msg': 'Timeout 1m15s exceeded'}`. Note that I'm not actually selecting "*"; I just replaced my actual query with an example placeholder. I have verified that when I use `limit 1000` at the end of my actual query, results get returned as expected so the error is simply a timeout one. Any ideas how to successfully increase the timeout with the new version of the Python SDK?

```
from couchbase.cluster import Cluster, ClusterOptions
from couchbase_core.cluster import PasswordAuthenticator
from couchbase.cluster import QueryOptions
import pandas as pd

cluster = Cluster("couchbase_url", ClusterOptions(PasswordAuthenticator("couchbase_username", "couchbase_password")))
cb = cluster.bucket("couchbase_bucket")
cb.n1ql_timeout = 5600
cb.timeout = 5600
cluster.n1ql_timeout = 5600
cluster.timeout = 5600 

result = cluster.query(f"""
                        select * from couchbase_bucket
                        """)

#result.timeout = 5600

data_list = []
for row in result:
    data_list.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(data_list)
df.head()
```

Comment: https://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-python-client/api/couchbase.html#n1ql-query-methods   check query_timeout

Comment: @vsr I tried this but am still getting the same timeout error...
`cluster = Cluster.connect(couchbase_url, ClusterOptions(PasswordAuthenticator(couchbase_username, couchbase_password), query_timeout=5600))`